# How to put image on top of fullscreen

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, fullscreen

I am creating silverlight video player.
I have organized my player as grid.
First row is video, second and third are control panels with buttons.

When I switch to fullscreen mode I want to set specified image on the top.
So i load image, resize and can't make this image to cover all elements(video,panels).
I try to make this image only visible, and cant do that.

I think there is possible to create an "element" and set it somehow to cover.
I would like do this like splash because i guess collapsing my rows isn't good idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by first making sure your image element is the last child in the Grid and by adding `Grid.RowSpan` value to it containing the number of rows in the grid:-

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <MediaElement ... />
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">...</StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">...</StackPanel>
  <Image Source="SomeImageUrl" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
</Grid>
```

An alternative to placing the `Image` at the end of the Grid's child list is to give it a higher ZIndex using rather unintuitively `Canvas.ZIndex` property.

Comment: I need to rescale image first, do you know how can i zoom image to resolution screen?

Comment: @David:  A decent jpeg image of say 1280x1024 should work fine withou the need for any specific scaling work on your part.